# Getting list of all consecutive intervals from series of dates in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, date

I have a list of LocalDates lets say 
14-06-2020, 15-06-2020, 17-06-2020, 19-06-2020, 20-06-2020, 21-06-2020 
and I want to have all consecutive intervals from above dates. So the output would be like

```
Interval 1 = [14-06-2020, 15-06-2020]
Interval 2 = [17-06-2020, 17-06-2020]
Interval 3 = [19-06-2020, 21-06-2020]
```

What would be the most efficient way to do in Java

So I have create an Interval class that would hold start and enddate

```
public class Interval{
  private LocalDate startDate;
  private LocalDate endDate;
}
```

I can iterate over each element in list of dates and then check for logic if two dates are consecutive something in below line,

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    dates.add(LocalDate.of(2020,6,14));
    dates.add(LocalDate.of(2020,6,15));
    dates.add(LocalDate.of(2020,6,17));
    dates.add(LocalDate.of(2020,6,19));
    dates.add(LocalDate.of(2020,6,21));
    dates.add(LocalDate.of(2020,6,20));

    Collections.sort(dates);

    //Handle if empty or null
    List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<>();
    if(dates==null || dates.size()==0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("list cannot be empty");
    }

    //If only one date then the interval starts and ends with same date
    if(dates.size()==1){
        Interval interval = new Interval();
        interval.setStartDate(dates.get(0));
        interval.setEndDate(dates.get(0));
    }
    LocalDate firstDate = dates.get(0);

    for(int i =1;i<dates.size(); i++){
        LocalDate endDate = dates.get(i);
        LocalDate nextDate = endDate.plusDays(1);
        //iterate over to get the desired list of interval
        while(my condition satisfies){
            //create new interval
        }
        //intervals.add(interval
    }
}
```

I wanted to check if there is something better using stream api or can i group dates by consecutive days and then collect them using interval

Comment: Please don't use `06` for months. It's an octal literal. Use `6`.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. updated question

Comment: You possibly meant `Interval 3 = [19-06-2020, 21-06-2020]`. Streams are not really a good option when it comes to maintaining an existing state and computing further. As it sounds though, the direction to look into could be to group all the dates with a difference of a day(consecutive) and then choose the first and the last for the interval.

Comment: @Naman thanks for pointing out. Yes I am beginning to feel that

Comment: Your rules for calculating "intervals" are unclear. Where does the duplicate 17th come from? Why 19–21 but no 20? (Also, I would generally recommend using ISO formatting of yyyy-MM-dd, which has the nice property of sorting in text format.)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Sorry for not making that clear. So you can consider interval as a date range. So if you have dates 06/12, 06/13 , 06/14, 06/16 (mm/dd). If i ask you what is the possible consecutive date ranges and I am only interested in start and end date, you will see that 12, 13, 14 are consecutive and hence date range is from 12th to 14th (start to end). Now, since 16th stands alone so the range is 16th to 16th (since this one finishes on same day).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "workaround" towards an approach based on `Stream` upon the sorted collection could be to use markers for range lookup -

```
List<Integer> rangeMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
rangeMarkers.add(0);
rangeMarkers.addAll(IntStream.range(0, dates.size() - 1)
        .filter(i -> !dates.get(i).plusDays(1).equals(dates.get(i + 1)))
        .mapToObj(i -> i + 1)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
rangeMarkers.add(dates.size());
System.out.println(rangeMarkers);
```

and then use those markers to map dates to `Interval` -

```
List<Interval> intervals = IntStream.range(0, rangeMarkers.size() - 1)
        .mapToObj(i -> new Interval(dates.get(rangeMarkers.get(i)),
                dates.get(rangeMarkers.get(i + 1) - 1)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(intervals);
```

Answer (score 1):

Stream API isn't your friend in this case. you can do it as I displayed the below but I think it isn't readable.

without non-stream API makes it more readable.

After sorting the list loop over the list by skipping the first index. current `localDate` is the first element in the list. by checking its equality with the other elements change the current value and merge `intervalMap`  as you see. for current localDate in the loop if equality isn't matched put it on the map with a new key. (`++index`). because you just want to have start `localDate` and end localDate in the merge function I just set the endLocalDate of the first `interVal` with the second interval endLocalDate value.

```
LocalDate current = dates.get(0);
Map<Integer, Interval> intervalMap2 = new HashMap<>();
int index = 1;
intervalMap2.put(1, new Interval(current,current));
for (LocalDate localDate : dates.subList(1, dates.size())) {
    if (current.plusDays(1).equals(localDate)) {
       current = localDate;
       intervalMap2.merge(index, new Interval(localDate,localDate), 
                    (val, val2) -> {val.setEndDate(val2.getEndDate());return val; });
    } else {
        intervalMap2.merge(index, new Interval(current,current),
              (val, val2) -> {val.setEndDate(val2.getEndDate());return val; });

        intervalMap2.put(++index, new Interval(localDate,localDate));
        current = localDate;
    }
}
```

however, if you interested in do it with stream version you can do like:

```
 Map<Integer, Interval> intervalMap = dates.stream().sorted()
            .collect(HashMap::new, (hashMap, localDate) -> {
                if (hashMap.get(hashMap.size()) != null &&
                        hashMap.get(hashMap.size()).getEndDate()
                                .equals(localDate.minusDays(1))) {
                    hashMap.merge(hashMap.size(),
                         new Interval(localDate, localDate),
                         (val, val2) -> {val.setEndDate(val2.getEndDate());return val; });
                } else {
                    if (hashMap.size() > 1)
                       hashMap.merge(hashMap.size(), hashMap.get(hashMap.size()),
                        (val, val2) -> { val.setEndDate(val2.getEndDate());return val;});
                 hashMap.put(hashMap.size() + 1, new Interval(localDate, localDate));
                }
            }, HashMap::putAll);
```